# bootstrap modal behind fade

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

***Hi all!***

By now I'm several hours into finding and understanding why I have this bug.

I'm working on a module for an open-source project based on Laraval and Bootstrap - Microweber(.com)

You can find the module at http://production.siteoplossing.nl

The idea is simple: Popup a Modale when the user its mouse leaves the browser

Now I have this working on another template, but at this particular template the 
`<div class="modal-backdrop">` is in front of `<div class="modal">` resulting in the webpage completely unusable.

I have tried:

1) **Z-index**

I have tried to fix this with Z-index. I have lowered the Z-index from `<div class="modal-backdrop">` to 8, resulting in `<div class="modal">` rise to the top only to see that the menu is unusable.

I have tried giving `<div class="modal">` a higher z-index (i.e. 16000) to see that it doesn't even come up.

*I believe this "solution" to be a simple hack which does not solve anything cause other problems keep arising.*

2) **Moving div Modal  in front of**

I thought about moving `<div class="modal">` in front of `</body>` - which does help. Only how could I achieve this? I can't simply put this code in front of the `</body>` tag because this is a module.

Hopefully somebody can help me here, as for now I'm stuck on this bug :)

***Thanks in advance!***

P.s. 
I have searched deep and throughout on StackOverFlow and Google before resulting to making a own question about this.

**I hope that someone can give me a solution and hopefully an answer why this occurred :)**

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Josh Janusch =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is quite simple, HTML  is like a layer system or a stack of elements.

So your page right now is like this in terms of stack:

```
     <html>
      / \
     /   \
<head>    <body> (simblings)
            |
            | (childs of body)
           / \
      ____/   \________
     /                 \
.modal-backdrop    #main-container
                         |
                         |
                   .content-holder
                         |
                         |
                     .container
                         |
                         |
                      .edit
                         |
                         |
              .module.module.module-microbounce
```

You just have to somehow on your code put `.modal-backdrop` as a sibling of `.module.module.module-microbounce`

Something like this:

```
     <html>
      / \
     /   \
<head>    <body> (simblings)
            |
            | (childs of body)
             \
              \________
                       \
                   #main-container
                         |
                         |
                   .content-holder
                         |
                         |
                     .container
                         |
                         |
                      .edit
                         |
                        / \
      _________________/   \________
     /                              \
.modal-backdrop     .module.module.module-microbounce
```

Or something like this (I prefer this one):

```
     <html>
      / \
     /   \
<head>    <body> (simblings)
            |
            | (childs of body)
           / \
      ____/   \_____________________________________________
     /                      |                               \
.modal-backdrop  .module.module.module-microbounce    #main-container
                                                            |
                                                            |
                                                      .content-holder
                                                            |
                                                            |
                                                        .container
                                                            |
                                                            |
                                                         .edit
```

### Edit

Or you could just change this:

```
// Fires modal when user exits
var _ouibounce = ouibounce(false, {
    aggressive: Agression,
    timer: 1,
    cookieExpire: CookieLength,
    callback: function() {
        $('#exitChoice').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Into this:

```
// Fires modal when user exits
var _ouibounce = ouibounce(false, {
    aggressive: Agression,
    timer: 1,
    cookieExpire: CookieLength,
    callback: function() {
        $('#exitChoice').appendTo('body').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Fabio Antunes! Going to see if I can make it happen.

Comment: No worries,  if this solves your problem remember to later mark this answer as correct

Comment: 1) Your solution is I believe comparable to what I have did at my step "2) Moving div Modal in front of" is it? I have tried your Stack Example 1 - I couldn't find ``modal-backdrop`` coded anywhere in my code and quickly learned that ``modal-backdrop`` is executed by bootstrap JS ( http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage ) .I wouldn't know how to manipulate that so its position can be altered. I have also checked out Stack Example 2 but I'm not yet sure how I could achieve this as adding a Module can only be done in the Childs of Body.

Comment: sorry for the late reply you are right, it's added by boostrap, that's why you have to put  your module just after the <body> opening tag

Comment: I have edited my answer with a proper solution for you, you just have to change one line of code

Comment: Don't worry about time, i'm already glad someone could help me further. Thank you very much Fabio for your time and knowledge! The Javascript change worked like a bliss!

Comment: I'm glad I could you help out, that's what this community is all about!